# How to eliminate a duplicate row in SQL by picking one

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a DB where there are `[Session]` and `[SessionAsset]` tables.

`SessionAsset` has a `ThumbnailUrl` that I want to get.

There are two `SessionAssets` associated with a single `Session`.

What would be the best way to take just 1 of those `ThumbnailUrl`s? If I join `Session` with `SessionAsset` on `SessionId` (primary key), then there will be duplicate rows.

Comment: use `SELECT TOP 1 <columnnames>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both records in `SessionAssets` have the same `ThumbnailUrl`, one solution would be to use a subquery that selects distinct `SessionId/ThumbnailUrl` tuples.

```
SELECT s.*, sa.ThumbnailUrl
FROM Session s
INNER JOIN ( -- or maybe LEFT JOIN ?
    SELECT DISTINCT SessionID, ThumbnailUrl FROM SessionAssets
) sa ON sa.SessionId = s.SessionID
```

---

If the `ThumbnailUrl`s are different and you want to get just one of them, then you might want to use aggregation :

```
SELECT s.*, sa.ThumbnailUrl
FROM Session s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SessionID, MAX(ThumbnailUrl) ThumbnailUrl 
    FROM SessionAssets 
    GROUP BY SessionID
) sa ON sa.SessionId = s.SessionID
```

Answer (score 0):

Join two tables through `[SessionId]`, and use `DISTINCT` keyword to eliminate duplicated `[ThumbnailUrl]`s.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ThumbnailUrl
FROM SessionAsset sa
JOIN Session s on s.SessionId = sa.SessionId
```

Comment: @HarshaB How do you mean? Isn't this the question asked for?

Comment: You shouldn't just dump code as an answer, explain what it does and how it solves the problem of the question.

Comment: @SalomonZhang : As Mark Rotteveel suggested in above comment, just add some explanation. So that SO will not consider it as low quality post.